# What is the purpose of the 3rd parameter (array) in a forEach callback?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The javascript `Array.prototype.forEach()` callback has the following form:

```
arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue[, index[, array]]) {
    //your iterator
}[, thisArg]);
```

The description of the array parameter is:

> array (Optional) The array that forEach() is being applied to.

My question is why does that array parameter even exist? Why wouldn't I just pass `arr` to the callback or reference it directly if it is in the same scope?

Comment: Because you could use the same callback for different arrays, then an access to the whole array is necessary.

Comment: *"Why wouldn't I just pass arr to the callback"* You are not calling the callback so you cannot pass anything to it. `forEach` calls the callback and that's why it passes the array to it.